# Specifying port in Ciao.write

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, http

As far as I know, Ciao uses port 80 as the default and I haven't found a way of changing the port it attempts to connect to.

I tried using `"192.168.0.23:8080"` but the `Ciao.write()` seems to timeout after a while. Is there a way to specify the port to use?

P.S I'm using an Arduino Uno WiFi DevEd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The factory firmware of Uno Wifi is discontinued.

[Uno WiFi and WiFi Link doc](https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-firmware-wifilink/blob/ota/UNOWIFI_DEV_ED.md)